# add class on each first-child of ul and remove on hover on each

Tags: jquery

I have a ul repeat as a different category. With the help of jquery i added the class on every first child of ul li, then i removed it whenever i hover on any li. But one of the defect is Whenever i hover on any element every category ul li first-child classes removed but I want only specefic ul li first-child class to be removed when hover at a time.

```
$(".product-left ul li:first-child img").addClass("first_child");

$(".product-left ul li ").mouseover(function() {
  $(".product-left ul li:first-child img" ).each.removeClass("first_child");
}).mouseout(function() { 
  $(".product-left ul li:first-child img").addClass("first_child");
});
```

html

```
<div class="product-left">



     <ul>
              <li><div class="pr_name"> <a href=" subproductpage.php?id=4"><div class="img_50_35">
        <img width="50" height="35" src="childsubcategory_image/20120925_085744_accomodation.gif"> </div>
        <span class="product_nm"> cosmo_sub_child_2 </span></a>
        </div>
  </li>
                 <li><div class="pr_name"> <a href=" subproductpage.php?id=3"><div class="img_50_35">
        <img width="50" height="35" src="childsubcategory_image/20120925_080004_search.gif"> </div>
        <span class="product_nm"> cosmo_sub_child </span></a>
        </div>
       </li>
                 </ul>




        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` within the `mouseover` event handler to refer to the element for which the event was triggered:

```
$(".product-left ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $("img", this).removeClass("first_child");
}).mouseout(function() { 
    $("img", this).addClass("first_child");
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the code doesnt remove the  first-child class

Comment: you can also use $(this).find('img').get()

Comment: $(".product-left ul li ").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('img').get().removeClass("first_child");
}).mouseout(function() { 
   $(this).find('img').get().addClass("first_child"); --- It doesnt remove the class on hovering..
});

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".product-left ul").find('img:eq(0)').addClass("first_child");
$(".product-left ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("img:eq(0)").removeClass("first_child");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("img:eq(0)").addClass("first_child");
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NNz9W/) with a

tag instead if  tag

**UPDATED CODE**

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZbMfC/)

Comment: It doesnt add any class to first-child img :(

Comment: Did you check the fiddle .. ??  Is it not how you want it.. Remove the class when hover for that particular ul and add the class back on mouse out

Comment: i am sorry for my unclear div format. I have updated it in my post. Yea i see you fiddle its working well i cant get it work in my div :(

Comment: Did you specify the first_child  class in the first place...?

Comment: Check the Updated fiddle above

Comment: $(".product-left ul li .pr_name").find('img:nth-child(0)').addClass("first_child");
$(".product-left ul li").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("img.first_child").removeClass("first_child");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("img:eq(0)").addClass("first_child");
}); I remove :eq(0) form the mouseover function and added .first_child its working.. thanks :)